# How to increase the font size of label names

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to increase the font size of label names. I tried with `geom_label_repel(aes(label = names, label.size = 5), box.padding = unit(0.5, "lines"))` . But the size doesn't affect the labels.

```
ggplot(df, aes(x,y,label=names)) +
  geom_point(colour = "red", size = 3) +
  geom_smooth(method=lm, se=FALSE, colour = "blue") +
  geom_label_repel(aes(label = names, label.size = 5),
                   box.padding = unit(0.5, "lines")) +
  xlim(0,2.5) +
  ylim(0,2.5) +
  theme( plot.title=element_text(size=16,face="bold"),
         axis.text=element_text(size=18),
         axis.title=element_text(size=20,face="bold"))
```

Comment: @M.D: I am not entirely sure, but I think this is not what OP asked for.

Comment: @M.D I don't need to  increase the size of  x and y axis labels. I would like to increase the size of label names on geom_point.

Comment: @Make42 You are Right!

Comment: Ok, now that I think about it: I'm really not sure what you (ashraf) want to do: Do you want the label size to be the same for all labels, or do you want the labels to be depended on a column of df? Your command is clearly wrong one way or the other. (Even if it might not throw an error that is!)

Comment: @Make42, you are right, scanned the question too fast and could not run the code without installing `ggrepel`.

Comment: Please accept the edit I did to your code: it was not very readable beforehand.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

As I just wrote in the comment, it is not clear from your code, whether you want the label size fixed (the same for all labels) or dependent on a column of `df`. Guess you want it fixed. In that case, setting the size is **not** done within `aes(...)`. Also, it is not necessary to repeat `label=names`. After reading https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggrepel/vignettes/ggrepel.html we can thus write:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x,y,label=names)) +
  geom_point(colour = "red", size = 3) +
  geom_smooth(method=lm, se=FALSE, colour = "blue") +
  geom_label_repel(size = 5,
                   box.padding = unit(0.5, "lines")) +
  xlim(0,2.5) +
  ylim(0,2.5) +
  theme( plot.title=element_text(size=16,face="bold"),
         axis.text=element_text(size=18),
         axis.title=element_text(size=20,face="bold"))
```

Comment: TL;DR version: `geom_label_repel(size = 5)`